# Time complexity of DFS in a 2D matrix (movement is 4 way and we reset visited flag each time we complete DFS at current node)

Tags: time-complexity, depth-first-search, space-complexity

Given a matrix of direction with L, R, U, D, at any point you can move to the direction which is written over the cell [i, j]. We have to tell minimum number of modifications to reach from [0, 0] to [N - 1, M - 1] .

```
    Example :-
    R R D
    L L L
    U U R

Answer is 1, we can modify cell [1, 2] from L To D.
```

What would be the time complexity for (the following) DFS solution? Notice how we are resetting the visited flag each time we explore a node.
Is it 4^(m*n)? Please explain the deduction with your answering. Thanks!

```
// minimumModification(arr, 0, 0, new boolean[arr.length][arr[0].length])       
private static int minimumModification(char[][] arr, int i, int j, boolean[][] visited)
{
    if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=arr.length || j>= arr[0].length || visited[i][j])
        return max;

    if(i == arr.length-1 && j == arr[0].length-1)
        return 0;

    visited[i][j] = true;
    int min = max;

    int right = minimumModification(arr, i, j+1, visited);
    int left = minimumModification(arr, i, j-1, visited);
    int down = minimumModification(arr, i+1, j, visited);
    int up = minimumModification(arr, i-1, j, visited);

    if(right != max && arr[i][j] != 'R')
        right++;
    if(left != max && arr[i][j] != 'L')
        left++;
    if(down != max && arr[i][j] != 'D')
        down++;
    if(up != max && arr[i][j] != 'U')
        up++;

    min = Math.min(min, right);
    min = Math.min(min, left);
    min = Math.min(min, down);
    min = Math.min(min, up);

    visited[i][j] = false;
    return min;
}

static final int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

source of question: Leetcode https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/476340/google-onsite-min-modifications

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm essentially works by trying every possible path from the top-left to the bottom-right of the grid, where each path is not allowed to visit a cell in the grid more than once. So the complexity should be about O(SARW(*m*, *n*)) where SARW(*m*, *n*) is the number of [self-avoiding walks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) on the grid which start in the top-left and end in the bottom-right. These are known as [self-avoiding rook walks](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html) according to Wolfram MathWorld; [an answer to a question on Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022245/number-of-self-avoiding-rook-walks-in-a-rectangular-grid) discusses the fact that no exact formula for counting them is known, but doesn't give any information about the asymptotic behaviour.

As far as I can tell, the order of growth is not known either. [This answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312993/number-of-self-avoiding-paths-on-a-grid-graph) claims that it should be exponential in the volume (i.e. m * n), but gives no upper bound on the base of that exponential, and no lower bound except that the base is greater than 1. The [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A007764) has exact numbers for the square case (m = n) for [n = 1 to 27](http://oeis.org/A007764/b007764.txt); I computed what exponential base would be implied by the numbers in that sequence, and found that it was increasing, but at a slower and slower rate, so it could level out somewhere around 1.7 or 1.8. That would give a complexity of about `O(1.8^(mn))`, but that's an estimate based on empirical data which could be way off.